# Подмена IP

Tags: ip, curl, php

Я написал скрипт, который парсит сайт средствами PHP. Меня заблокировали на этом сайте. Я скрипт разместил на другом хосте, но после 1000 страниц меня снова заблокировали. При парсинге я выдаю нормальные заголовки браузера используя CURL. Можно ли как-нибудь сделать так, чтобы скрипт отдавал на сайт левый IP ?

Comment: Купите себе proxy IP: они копейки стоят и каждый час обновляются. И будет счастье :)

Comment: [Вот ловите][1].


  [1]: http://www.poststar.ru/proxy_my.htm

Comment: Спасибо за оперативность, а можно для тех кто в танке по подробнее?

Comment: че минусанули чела?

Answer (score 1):

Ничего сложного, в опциях курла добавьте:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "217.76.35.238:3128");
```

Comment: с прокси разобрался, но мне это не помогло, из-за чего еще могут заблокировать.
я вставляю нормальные куки, отправляю куки как в моем браузере, что еще нужно учесть?

Comment: 1. Используйте только анонимные HTTP прокси!
2. Стоит учесть браузеры, генерируйте несколько для отвода глаз.

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; En; rv:1.8.0.2) Gecko/20070306 Firefox/1.0.0.4");